# How to an anchor (View) can add multiple List popup window and positioning each listpopupwindow to the anchor?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

As the title, I'd like to associate multiple List Popup Window to a anchor (a view).
For example: one above, one below, one left and one right of the anchor. But I have no idea if it's possible?
Can you explain my problem?
1) How to add multiple ListPopupWindows to a anchor?
2) If above condition is possible, how would I be able to position each ListPopupWindow to the anchor?

Your comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible in Android! :) I have no time to write for you, but here is the hint.

Create a layout xml file for a grid (TableLayout seems to be the best, but RelativeLayout or nested LinearLayout-s will also do):

```
    @id/topLeft       @id/toP      @id/topRight
    @id/left           Anchor      @id/right
    @id/bottomLeft    @id/bottom   @id/bottomRight
```

All placeholder views are declared as FrameLayout. When you need to add what you call "popup window" (name it `popupView`) use something like this:

```
     ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.right)).addView(popupView);
```

Comment: According to your suggestion, I've found a way to resolve my issue. Thank you anyway